# Saturation of a module and local cohomology

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-cohomology

> Let $R=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be a polynomial ring over some field $k$, 
>   let $M$ be an $R$-module and $M^{\text{sat}}$ the saturation of $M$.
>   Denote by $m$ the maximal ideal of $R$. Is it true that: 
>   $$ H^i_{m}(M) \simeq H^i_{m}(M^{\text{sat}}) \text{ for }i\geq 1\ ?$$

Here every $R$-module is graded, and by $M^{\text{sat}}$ I mean the global sections of the associated sheaf in the projective space $\text{Proj}(S)$.

Comment: What is saturation of a module for you?

Comment: The global sections of the sheafification, if that makes sense.

Comment: For affine varieties, this is just the module itself. So, I think you probably mean something else.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I will add that every module is $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$-graded and the sheafification is in the corresponding projective space.

Answer (score 1):

With your comment, this is in general false. As an example, take $R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_4]$ and $S=k[u^4,u^3v,uv^3,v^4]$ which is a quotient of $R$ by sending $x_1\mapsto u^4, x_2\mapsto u^3v$ etc. Then, the saturation of $S$ is $T=k[u^4,u^3v,u^2v^2, uv^3, v^4]$. $S$ has depth one and $T$ has depth 2. Thus, the first local cohomology of $S$ is non-zero, but that of $T$ is zero.